# Why do some people like use in' to symbolize ing?

Tags: american-english, spelling, eye-dialect

In some movies or songs, "in'" is used instead of "ing". For example: "Searchin' high". The "Searchin'" is "Searching". Or "Lookin' for a place where I can go". The "Lookin'" is "Looking". Someone told me that is American culture because they often miss off the last consonants of a word, especially the "g" in "ing". Is that right?

Comment: It's not part of 'American culture' - dropping the 'g' of '-ing' is common in informal British English too, and, I suspect, of most Englishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard pronunciation of "-ing" uses a /ŋ/ sound (not /ng/).  In most dialects, this sound is very close to /n/ and in casual speech /ŋ/ tends to get pronounced as /n/.

To indicate this casual pronunciation, it is quite common to spell with "in" and an apostrophe.

> I'm lookin' at you.

This is sometimes called "eye-dialect".  You deliberately spell a word as it is pronounced in a particular dialect, in order to let the reader know how a speaker is speaking.

Naturally, in careful speech, /ŋ/ is fully produced and unless you want to indicate a particular casual pronunciation you should always write "ing"

So, it's not "culture".

Answer (score 0):

**When writers, including songwriters and poets**, want to imitate speech in writing and the way some people drop the g sound in ing, or /ŋ/, they use apostrophes for that.

**It is not just AmE**. Dropping the g is present in various dialects of English.